# Altering the modal size to ensure that form header and footers are visible at all times on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have been reading quite a few blogs on here but cant seem to find the right css to amend or fix my issue.

Out theme currently uses a form for applicants to send in CV's. When the modal is adjusted to respond to mobile devices it seems that the apply button, which is on the footer is not visible thus creating two scrolls which users cant really see.

[image: current mobile view]

I would like some help with CSS to ensure that the header and footer are visible on all devices with the content in the middle to be scroll-able.
Here is the current HTml being used:

```html
<div id="jobboard-modal-apply" class="jobboard-modal md-modal md-effect-1 md-show">
    <div class="md-content">
        <a class="md-close" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></i></a>

<form class="jobboard-form apply-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-title">
        <span></span>
        <h5>Application</h5>
        <h4>CRM Developer</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="form-content">
        
<div class="form-fields" tabindex="0" style="width: 380px; padding-right: 0px; outline: none; overflow: hidden;">

    
<div class="row">

<div class="field col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 field-media field-validate">
    <div class="field-header">
        <label class="field-name" for="cv">CV *</label>
            </div>
    <div class="field-content">

<div class="file type-file">
            <div class="file-thumb" title="Uploaded : 2018-11-23 11:10:08">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i>
                    </div>
        <div class="file-info">
            <span class="file-name">Adrian-Gatts-CV.docx</span>
            <span class="file-date">Uploaded 27 days ago</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<input id="cv" type="file" class="field-media" name="cv" data-type="pdf,doc,docx,rtf" data-type-notice="File format not supported, you can only upload the following &quot;pdf,doc,docx,rtf&quot; file." data-size="1024" data-size-notice="You can not upload files larger than 1024Kb">
<button type="button" class="file-select">Select CV</button>
        </div>
</div>

</div>

</div><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: none; left: 405px; top: 131px;"><div class="enscroll-track vertical-track" style="position: relative; height: 300px;"><a href="" class="vertical-handle" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 300px;"><div class="top"></div><div class="bottom"></div></a></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="apply-button btn btn-default btn-xlg">Apply for this job</button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="861bb0a682"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/job/crm-developer/">    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="7703">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="apply_job">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="jobboard-form">
</form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you can reproduce the same output in the snippet here, that would be great.